# How can I restrict MongoDB to only use one CPU/core?

Tags: mongodb

If I understand correctly, the `mongod` process will use all available cores (at least for read operations).

I would like to limit it to only use one core, is that possible?

I'm using Mongo 3.6.

Thanks!

Comment: Limit number of available cores to 1 on system level? eg. with taskset.